# How to add a Secondary NameNode in a HBase cluster setup?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I've a Hbase cluster setup with 3 nodes: A NameNode and 2 DataNodes. 
The NameNode is a server with 4GB memory and 20GB hard disk while each DataNode has 8GB memory and 100GB hard disk.

I'm using
Apache Hadoop version: 2.7.2 and 
Apache Hbase version: 1.2.4

I've seen some people mentioned about a Secondary NameNode.

My questions are,

1. What is the impact of not having a Secondary NameNode in my setup?
2. Is it possible to use one of the DataNodes as the Secondary NameNode?
3. If possible how can I do it? (I inserted only the NameNode in /etc/hadoop/masters file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the impact of not having a Secondary NameNode in my setup?

`SecondaryNamenode` does the job of periodically merging the namespace image with the edit log (called as checkpointing). Your setup is not an High-Availability setup, thus not having one will cause the edit log to grow large in size which would eventually add an overhead to the NameNode during startup.

> 2. Is it possible to use one of the DataNodes as the Secondary NameNode?

Running the SNN in a Datanode host is not recommended. A separate host is preferred to run the Secondary Namenode process. The host chosen for SNN must have identical memory as the NN.

> 3. If possible how can I do it? (I inserted only the NameNode in /etc/hadoop/masters file.)

`masters` file is not in use anymore. Add this property in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
   <value>SNN_host:50090</value>
</property>
```

Also note that, SecondaryNamenode process is started by default in the node where `start-dfs.sh` is executed.

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo . Do both namenodes have to have the same hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: What is the best solution for a HA setup: Secondary Namenode, Checkpoint node or Backup node?

Comment: There is no secondary namenode in HA. The standby namenode takes care of checkpointing. If you have questions related to HA, please open a new question with high-availability tag.